# Issue with getting pagination to work with mssql

Tags: php, html, sql-server, pdo

I have am trying to get this pagination table setup but for some reason I get this error now it was working with MySQL but when I switch it to MSSQL. I get this error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with  message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pagination\index.php:40 Stack trace:#0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pagination\index.php(40): PDOStatement->execute()#1
>   {main}thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pagination\index.php on line 40 
>   Line 40 is near the Stmt2 execute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Receiving</title>
        <!-- CSS File -->
    <link href="css/pagination.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
 <body>
<?php
require_once ("db_connect.php");

// No. of adjacent pages shown on each side
$adjacents = 2;
// We will assign variable here for entry By. you can use your variables here.
$EntryBy = "completed";
// We Will prepare SQL Query
$STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DateRequested FROM receivingrequests WHERE Status = :Status");
// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
$STM->bindParam(':Status', $EntryBy);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
$STM->execute();
// Count no. of records
$Records = $STM->rowCount();
// Your File Name will be the same like your php page name which is index.php
$targetpage = "index.php";
// Below is setting for no. of records per page.
$limit = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
if ($page)
// First Item to dipaly on this page
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
  else
// if no page variable is given, set start to 0
$start = 0;
// Get data using PDO prepare Query.
$STM2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `RequestNumber`,`DATEREQUESTED`, `EmpName` ,`Department` ,`VasLblDate` ,`Status` FROM receivingrequests WHERE Status = :Status ORDER BY RequestNumber LIMIT $start, $limit");
// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
$STM2->bindParam(':Status', $EntryBy);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
$STM2->execute();
// We will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results later in bottom of the page.
$STMrecords = $STM2->fetchAll();
// Setup page variables for display. If no page variable is given, default to 1.
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
// previous page is page - 1
$prev = $page - 1;
// next page is page + 1
$next = $page + 1;
// lastpage is = total Records / items per page, rounded up.
$lastpage = ceil($Records / $limit);
// last page minus 1
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
// Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
$pagination = "";
if ($lastpage > 1)
    {
    $pagination.= "<div class='pagination'>";
    // previous button
    if ($page > 1) $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>Previous</a>";
      else $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Previous</span>";
    // pages
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
            if ($counter == $page) $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
              else $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
            }
        }
    elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
        // close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if ($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                if ($counter == $page) $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                  else $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
            }
        // in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif ($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                if ($counter == $page) $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                  else $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
            }
        // close to end; only hide early pages
          else
            {
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                if ($counter == $page) $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                  else $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                }
            }
        }
    // next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>Next</a>";
      else $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Next</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";
    }
// Below is a start of table in which we will show records using foreach loop.
// We use foreach loop here to echo records.
foreach($STMrecords as $r)
    {
    echo "<table width='100%' class='mytableP'>";
    echo "<tr><th>RequestNumber</th><th>DateRequested</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Department</th><th>VasLablDate</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $r[5] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br />";
    }
// For showing pagination below the table we will echo $pagination here after </table>. For showing above the table we will echo $pagination before <table>
echo $pagination;
// Closing MySQL database connection
$dbh = null;
?>
  </body>
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is MySQL syntax, not SQL Server syntax. You'll need to use [`OFFSET / FETCH` for SQL Server 2012+](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch), or [more archaic methods for older versions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/69892/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason for the error are the `` ` `` characters mysql uses to quote attribute names. MSSQL uses `[` and `]`.

Just delete the ` characters, they are not necassary as long as you don't use reserved words as table attributes.

**Edit:**
As for the LIMIT issue: You could use doctrine DBAL library, a simple PDO wrapper. The core syntax is the same like the PDO Syntax, but you have nice features like the querybuilder:
http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

With the querybuilder you can use `->setFirstResult()` and `->setMaxResults()` that emulate the limit function from mysql.

But what @AaronBertrand wrote in a comment above (use OFFSET / FETCH) is much easier if you use SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: That syntax aside, the script still assumes `LIMIT` is valid in SQL Server.

Comment: By the way, I needed some trial and error to format the ` as code in my answer, as itself is used to format code. This worked:  <code>\\`</code>

Comment: what would I replace limit with. I am little confused on how to get this to work with mssql

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right of course, I was a bit too hasty.
I editet my answer above.

Comment: Using Doctrine and setFirstResult/setMaxResults with mssql throws an error: "Platform mssql does not support offset values in limit queries." (even though you'd expect Doctrine to map the query to OFFSET/FETCH in this case).